# IntelliJ compile for Java 7 JRE using Java 8 SDK

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, java-7, java-8

I have the Java 8 SDK and runtime, and a project that is only using Java 7 features. I was wondering whether I could set up intellij to build a Java-7-level jar, something that is definitely possible from command line?

So far, I have tried simply setting the project language level to 7 as an experiment, but that is obviously insufficient and not really what I need.

I have also seen this question on SO: "[Intellij IDEA using java7 compiler to compile when I have configured it to use Java6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756469/intellij-idea-using-java7-compiler-to-compile-when-i-have-configured-it-to-use-j)", but my project SDK is already set up to the newest Java version, and I merely need a Java-7-compatible artifact/jar compilation.

EDIT: I only have Java 6 and Java 8 JREs/SDKs on my local system because unfortunately Java 7 has issues on my system and is not compatible.

Comment: I think you need to set the project language level. Eclipse could do this too using a lower version compiler, so I'm fairly certain IntelliJ can do it too.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it didn't work. (See 2nd paragraph)

Comment: Can you clarify "that is obviously insufficient and not really what I need."  Which build tool are you using e.g. `ant` or `maven`?

Comment: ah, found it, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Project bytecode version -> 1.7

Answer (score 12):

- Select root of your project.
- Press F4
- Select language level.

[image]

Comment: You have to have this set as well really to actually solve the OP's problem. It certainly solved it for me.

Comment: You saved my day