# java 8 with Glassfish 4.1 Artifact HelloWorld:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available

Tags: java, spring, web-services, intellij-idea, glassfish

I create a simple java web service project in intellij idea and configured the glassfish 4.1 server. and just run the application. output window shows the following messages

> C:\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
>   Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
>   [2015-06-10 01:35:00,667] Artifact HelloWorld:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
>   Detected server admin port: 4848
>   Detected server http port: 8080

server is running fine. but webservice is not deployed. can anyone help me.

> I use java 8. intellij 14, glassfish 4.1 and windows 8.1

I followed following posts, but none of these are helps me.
[post one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365498/problems-with-glassfish-4-debug-in-idea-12-1) , [post two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756469/intellij-idea-using-java7-compiler-to-compile-when-i-have-configured-it-to-use-j) , [post 03](http://www.coderanch.com/t/623883/glassfish/unable-deploy-simple-spring-project), [post 04](http://www.ivonet.it/Java/IntelliJ-Glassfish-Deploy)

I spend last two day to find an answer, please help me.

Comment: I have the same problem can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Check your Facets and your Artifacts are all right. Facets must have web deployment description and Web Resource description, the absolute path is all right.

Check the Artifact output directory, make directories:

1. WEB-INF/class/{your compile output},
2. the resource directory for example web app directory content.

I think the IntelliJ use ant as it's deployment tools, then you can image how it work, just denote the path the project need